# SharpPCap Keeps Printing Out "Is an IP Packet"

Tags: c#, sharppcap

All of the sudden, i have no clue what i did, my application started printing out: "Is an IP packet".

Has this ever happened to anyone else? Here is the code for my OnPacketArrival event:

```
 #region " Global Variables "
    public static bool fTCP = true;
    public static bool fIP = true;
    public static bool fICMP4 = false;
    public static bool fICMP6 = false;
    public static bool fIGMP = false;
    public static bool fPPPoE = false;
    public static bool fWOL = false;
    public static bool fUDP = false;
    public static bool fARP = false;
    public static bool fLLDP = false;
    static public string f = "";
    static public int intro = 0;
    static public bool log = false;
    static public string logFileLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\packetLog.log";
    #endregion




    private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var raw_tcp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var tcp = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_tcp);
            var raw_ip = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var ip = IpPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_ip);
            var raw_udp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var udp = UdpPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_udp);
            var raw_icmpv4 = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var icmpv4 = ICMPv4Packet.GetEncapsulated(raw_icmpv4);
            var raw_icmpv6 = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var icmpv6 = ICMPv6Packet.GetEncapsulated(raw_icmpv6);
            var raw_pppoe = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var pppoe = PPPoEPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_pppoe);
            var raw_lldp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var lldp = LLDPPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_lldp);
            var raw_wolp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var wolp = WakeOnLanPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_wolp);
            var raw_igmp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var igmp = IGMPv2Packet.GetEncapsulated(raw_igmp);
            var raw_arp = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var arp = ARPPacket.GetEncapsulated(raw_arp);
            if (udp != null)
            {
                string hour_tcp = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Hour.ToString();
                string min_tcp = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Minute.ToString();
                string sec_tcp = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Second.ToString();
                string msec_tcp = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Millisecond.ToString();
                int len_tcp = e.Packet.Data.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("hr{0}:{1}:{2}:{3} Length={4} p={5} -> {6} Type={7}", hour_tcp, min_tcp, sec_tcp, msec_tcp, len_tcp, udp.SourcePort, udp.DestinationPort, "UDP/Packet");
            }
            else
            {
                string hour = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Hour.ToString();
                string min = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Minute.ToString();
                string sec = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Second.ToString();
                string msec = e.Packet.Timeval.Date.Millisecond.ToString();
                int len = e.Packet.Data.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("hr{0}:{1}:{2}:{3} Length={4}", hour, min, sec, msec, len);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The following error occured. Please let me know, ASAP!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            CaptureDeviceList devices = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
            if (devices.Count < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("No devices were found on this machine! :O");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);
                return;
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("The following devices are available on this machine:");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Print out the available network devices
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ICaptureDevice dev in devices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" - {0}) {1}\n", i, dev.ToString());
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please select a device to monitor . . . ");
            i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Extract a device from the list


            ICaptureDevice device = devices[i];


            device.OnPacketArrival += new SharpPcap.PacketArrivalEventHandler(device_OnPacketArrival);


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing . . . ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to set a filter for the packets that are displayed?");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Yes or No . . . ");
            string yn1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (yn1.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Select the filter you would like applied:");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 1. TCP");
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 2. UDP");
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 3. IP");
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 4. TCP & IP");
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 5. TCP & UDP");
                Console.WriteLine(" -- 6. IP & UDP");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Enter the corresponding number for the filter you wish to activate . . . ");
                string p = Console.ReadLine();
                if (p == "1")
                {
                    f = "tcp";
                }
                else if (p == "2")
                {
                    f = "udp";
                }
                else if (p == "3")
                {
                    f = "ip";
                }
                else if (p == "4")
                {
                    f = "tcp and ip";
                }
                else if (p == "5")
                {
                    f = "tcp and udp";
                }
                else if (p == "6")
                {
                    f = "ip and udp";
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to set the capture mode? (If no, default is to" + Environment.NewLine + "capture all traffic.)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please input Yes or No . . . ");
            string ynsetcap = Console.ReadLine();
            string devmode = "";
            int readTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
            if (ynsetcap == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" --- 1. Device Mode Promiscuous [a]");
                Console.WriteLine(" --- 2. Device Mode Normal [b]");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press the corresponding number to set it or the letter for more info.");
                Console.Write("Waiting for input . . . ");
                devmode = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (ynsetcap == "no")
            {
                device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
                goto s;
            }

            if (devmode == "1")
            {
                device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            }
            else if (devmode == "2")
            {
                device.Open(DeviceMode.Normal, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            }
            else if (devmode.ToLower() == "a")
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("The promiscuous Device Mode displays all network traffic. Even traffic" + Environment.NewLine + "that is not intended for the device that is currently being monitored." + Environment.NewLine + "Would you like to set the device to this mode?");
                Console.Write("Please input Yes or No . . . ");
                string ynsetprom = Console.ReadLine();
                if (ynsetprom.ToLower() == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Device Mode set to promiscuous!");
                    device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);

                }
                else if (ynsetprom.ToLower() == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Device Mode set to Normal!");
                    device.Open(DeviceMode.Normal, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);
                }
            }
            else if (devmode.ToLower() == "b")
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("The normal Device Mode displays only network traffic intended" + Environment.NewLine + "for the current device." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Would you like to set the mode to Normal?");
                Console.Write("Please input Yes or No . . . ");
                string ynsetnorm = Console.ReadLine();
                if (ynsetnorm.ToLower() == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Device Mode set to Normal!");
                    device.Open(DeviceMode.Normal, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);
                }
                else if (ynsetnorm.ToLower() == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Device Mode set to Promiscuous!");
                    device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3750);
                }
            }
        s:
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" --- Listening on {0}, press the 'Enter'" + Environment.NewLine + "key to stop...", device.Description);


            if (f.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    device.Filter = f;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("The following error occured: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7500);
                }


            }

            // Start the capturing process
            device.StartCapture();

            // Wait for 'Enter' from the user.
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Stop the capturing process
            device.StopCapture();

            // Close the pcap device
            device.Close();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Capture has stoped and the device stream has been closed." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to exit . . .");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("The following error occured. Please inform me, ASAP!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here is the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40671650/wtf.png

Any help on why it is doing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that all of the code? I would have expected to see an `if` block containing `Console.WriteLine("Is an IP Packet");`. I don't recall seeing it written by SharpPCap.

Comment: Exactly. I have no clue why it started doing that all of the sudden. I used the search function to try and find `Console.WriteLine("Is an IP Packet");` or just `"Is an IP Packet"` but found it no where in my project. :O

Comment: Are you using a custom build of SharpPCap?

Comment: Nope. Directly downloaded from the article on CodeProject. It randomly started doing it. Never happened before, then, i debugged it, and bam.

Comment: Just a random suggestion, try downloading the _official_ binary from the project site and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Alright, i downloaded it from Tamir Gal's site, the developer, and it does the same thing. It started doing it when i added all the extra packet types. But then i removed everything and started only using one at a time to see if i could narrow it down to which one was doing it but they all did the same thing. I have no clue why it started doing this...

Comment: Chris Morgan is the official developer now and I _believe_ the official release is [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) from SourceForge. It doesn't write anything to the console from my experience, so it has to be coming from your application code (and definitely not the code you posted). Without more detail about your application or scouring your application ourselves, I'm not sure how much any of us can help.

Comment: I downloaded the binary from the SF page. I can send you my source if you would like, i just don't want to post it publicly.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a limited example?

Comment: Updated OP, i still don't see how it was something i did. I could be overlooking it, though! Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: You're saying this example produces the same results? I can't recreate it. Perhaps the best recourse would be to download the SharpPCap source and debug it within your code to identify where the output is coming from. I have the latest (release) SharpPCap source on my PC and I don't see how it could produce such output.

Comment: Sorry, i just deleted it. Not that informative anyways. :p Thanks once again everyone. Y'all saved me! :D

Comment: Just wanted to say that I removed it from git master of packet.net. A new release with a ton of 802.11 packet support is coming soon and this fix will be included in that release. Again, sorry about that, the Console.WriteLine() shouldn't have made it into the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its coming from the [`IGMPv2Packet`](http://packetnet.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=packetnet/packetnet;a=blob;f=PacketDotNet/IGMPv2Packet.cs;h=aef6a017986c5449d9c50ac129c029ac3b2eabf6;hb=HEAD#l152) parser of Packet.Net:

Your code:

```
var igmp = IGMPv2Packet.GetEncapsulated(raw_igmp);
```

Packet.Net code:

```
     public static IGMPv2Packet GetEncapsulated(Packet p)
     {
         if(p is InternetLinkLayerPacket)
         {
             var payload = InternetLinkLayerPacket.GetInnerPayload((InternetLinkLayerPacket)p);
             if(payload is IpPacket)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Is an IP packet");
                 var innerPayload = payload.PayloadPacket;
                 if(innerPayload is IGMPv2Packet)
                 {
                     return (IGMPv2Packet)innerPayload;
                 }
             }
         }

         return null;

     }
```

Comment: +1 - Never considered it would be coming from Packet.net. Good catch! If you include an explicit suggested note for what should be changed (not everyone realizes they can change the source), your answer may be more helpful to those that come across this in the future.

Comment: I didn't think about that either. O_O

Comment: I just dropped a break on your first line in the giant try/catch and when it broke hit F10 until it dumped that message out which lead me to that class. Got to love step over.

Comment: Oops. I must have left that print in there when debugging. I'll make sure it is removed from the development branch so it won't be present in the next release coming in the best future. Sorry about that.